# How to break line before lstlisting environment?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, ntheorem

I am typesetting answers to textbook exercises. I use a `ntheorem` theorem named `question`as wrapper for the questions. Some of the answers begin with regular text, and I want them to start on the same line as the incipit Question number XX.

To achieve this, I defined

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
```

However, some answers only consist in a piece of code that I typeset with a custom `lstlisting` environment

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{lstcaml}[1][]{\lstset{language=[Objective]caml, frame=single, frameround=tttt, #1}}{}
```

within the `question` environment. In this case I want the listing to start on the next line, for code indentation reasons and to get an unbroken frame around it.

It does not work as I expected :

[image: Result of MWE]

is obtained from

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{question}
     Some text
     \begin{lstcaml}
        Some code
     \end{lstcaml}
   \end{question}

  \begin{question}

    \begin{lstcaml}
       Some code
    \end{lstcaml}
  \end{question}
  %% the same follows without borders for listings
```

I tried to add a `\par` in the definition of my listings environnment, to no avail (I had to cheat with `\let\mypar\par` because these tokens seem to be used in a non-`\long` definition).

Manually typing `\ \\` at the beginning works but it is cumbersome and I think it takes more vertical space than needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to have something, like a letter or `\strut` or `\leavevmode`, after the theorem title:

```
\begin{question}\leavevmode
  \begin{lstcaml}
    Some code
  \end{lstcaml}
\end{question}
```

To do this for all instances you can define your own theorem style. Here I have taken the theorem style for `plain` and added a `\strut` outside the theorem title (`\theoremseparator` turns up inside the title and cannot be used for this). A total MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{myplain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]\leavevmode}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{myplain}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{lstcaml}[1][]{\lstset{language=[Objective]caml, frame=single, frameround=tttt, #1}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
  Some text
  \begin{lstcaml}
    Some code
  \end{lstcaml}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \begin{lstcaml}
    Some code
  \end{lstcaml}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

As pointed out by ysalmon, the same can achieved by seting the `\leavevmode` in the `lstcaml` definition. Then the preamble becomes:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{lstcaml}[1][]{\leavevmode\lstset{language=[Objective]caml, frame=single, frameround=tttt, #1}}{}
```

Comment: Usually this means you need to \leavevmode.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, yes that might be even better. I have updated

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, defining `\lstnewenvironment{lstcaml}[1][]{\leavevmode\lstset{language=[Objective]caml, frame=single, frameround=tttt, #1}}{}` works too and seems a little simpler.

Comment: @ysalmon, Even better. It should give the same result and you don't have to define your own `plain`. I have added it to the answer.